# Powershell formatting

Tags: powershell

I am pretty new to powershell and have been trying various ways to split the results from the following powershell script I found but have had no luck. At the moment the script list everything in 4 columns with no gap in between the results of each server. 
(when it finishes with the results for one server I would like a gap or even a header with the server name between each result to make it easier to read when run against multiple servers)
any help to get this formatted would be appreciated.

```
  Get-WmiObject -ComputerName ("server1","server2") Win32_UserProfile | % {
  $userinfo = [WMI] ($_.__Path -Replace "Win32_UserProfile", "Win32_SID")
  New-Object PsObject -Property @{
  ComputerName= $_.__Server 
  Domain      = $userinfo.ReferencedDomainName
  User        = $userinfo.AccountName
  LastUsed    = $_.ConvertToDatetime($_.LastUseTime)

 }
 } | export-csv -NoType c:\Results.csv
```

**This is what I am trying to do**

```
server 1
user    lastModified    
bob     8/20/14 
billy   7/20/14    
Carla   6/12/14

server 2
user    lastModified 
bob     8/20/14 
billy   7/20/14    
Carla   6/12/14

server 3
user    lastModified 
bob     8/20/14 
billy   7/20/14    
Carla   6/12/14
```

**This is what I am getting at the moment**

```
lastUsed   user   computername
8/20/14    bob    server 1
6/20/14    billy  server 1
9/1/14     sam    server 3
3/2/14     sonny  server 4
```

So when you throw in 50 60 profiles all piled up like that its pretty much unreadable especially if you try and sort by date because then the servers are just all over the place.

I also get this error every time that I run the script, although I still get the results and the script produces what it is supposed to.

> Exception calling "ConvertToDateTime" with "1" argument(s): "Exception calling "ToDateTime" with "1" argument(s): "Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
>   Parameter name: dmtfDate""
>   At line:13 char:33
>   +             $*.ConvertToDatetime <<<< ($*.LastUseTime)
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ScriptMethodRuntimeException

Thanks again for the help

Comment: It would be a lot easier if you show us desired output. Else the community might get it wrong what you are looking for and be wasting everyone's time.

Comment: Sure - What I need is the list of all the folders in the "users" folder for several servers with the user, last time folder was used and the server name. Basically I need to find what profile folders have been stale for a while then out put that into excel or HTML. This script does exactly what I need but has no formatting. I will show an example above of what I am trying to get

Comment: I wonder if the error occurs if there is no value for `LastUsedTime`... perhaps it is null if the user never logged in.

Comment: now that its organized I do see some blank rows and rows with user but no date - so what you just said makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$toFile = "C:\temp\TEST.CSV"
$header = "Computer","Domain","User","LastUsed"
$computers = "kanimage02","kanantivirus01"

ForEach($singleComputer in $computers){
    Add-Content -Path $toFile -Value "$singleComputer`n$($header -join ',')"
    Get-WmiObject -ComputerName ($singleComputer) Win32_UserProfile | ForEach-Object{
        $userinfo = [WMI] ($_.__Path -Replace "Win32_UserProfile", "Win32_SID")
        Add-Content -Path $toFile -Value (@(
            $_.__Server 
            $userinfo.ReferencedDomainName
            $userinfo.AccountName
            $_.ConvertToDatetime($_.LastUseTime)
        ) -Join ",")

    }
    Add-Content -Path $toFile -Value ""
}
```

I was having a real issue trying to get `Export-Csv` to try and repeat the headers. The simple approach would have been multiple calls by moving `Export-Csv` into piped output of your `ForEach-Object`. However `Export-Csv` does not have a `-StopBeingHelpful` switch meaning that regardless of what I did it noticed that the header was already there and felt no need to repeat it. Since what you are asking for is not a *true* csv file output I had a much easier time with `Add-Content`. So a little breakdown of whats going on here

1. I put your computers into a string array called `$computers`
2. Your `Get-WmiObject` loop is mostly the same accept that instead of making a `customPSObject` i just made a simple array. Again this was to stop PowerShell from treating it special. in practice it seemed pointless to create a `CustomPSObject` to convert it to an array just to export it!
3. The *csv* portion of this comes from `-join` I take the arrays and join them with commas to create a csv output. During each loop run place a header down that contains the computer name on one line and the header on the next. WMI data follows. Insert a blank line between loops for segregation like in your sample.
4. You sample ignores some of the data you are collecting. I output all data but you could change the `$header` and array contents to suit your needs.

Some sample output would look like this:

```
kanimage02
Computer,Domain,User,LastUsed
KANIMAGE02,NT AUTHORITY,NETWORK SERVICE,9/11/2014 10:25:19 AM
KANIMAGE02,NT AUTHORITY,LOCAL SERVICE,9/11/2014 10:25:24 AM
KANIMAGE02,NT AUTHORITY,SYSTEM,2/22/2011 12:07:14 PM

kanantivirus01
Computer,Domain,User,LastUsed
KANANTIVIRUS01,NT AUTHORITY,NETWORK SERVICE,9/10/2014 3:19:03 AM
KANANTIVIRUS01,NT AUTHORITY,LOCAL SERVICE,9/10/2014 3:19:08 AM
KANANTIVIRUS01,NT AUTHORITY,SYSTEM,2/22/2011 12:07:14 PM
```

Note that at no point during this do I clear the file. If it already contains content it will all be appended.

Comment: WOW - That's pretty much what I needed - I should be able to figure out any other changes - I did notice when I run it even though I get the results I get this error (this was already an issue - did not appear from anything you did) Is this error what you mean by it ignores some data?                                           Exception calling "ConvertToDateTime" with "1" argument(s):

Comment: If its something simple might be able to address it. Include it in the question. If its something involved it might better serve as another question.

Comment: You are welcome. At SO you can show your appreciation by marking a good answer as accepted and/or upvoting answers. Again, you are welcome

Comment: Will do - I added the error to the question as well